# is it possible to integrate AJAX Datatables with Laravel without package?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, datatable

I wonder if I can integrate `AJAX Datatables` processing server side feature with `Laravel 5.4` without using package from `Yajra`. I try `Yajra` but I guess it overkill to use only on a `datatables`, also it still has some bug that I faced.

If someone ever try to use `Datatables AJAX` feature with `Laravel 5.4`, please tell me how to do it? Especially what must I send to controller like how can I send `JSON` and view at the same time which will get me an error when I try to do it.

Comment: You can manually import the .css and .js files from datatables...

Comment: @lewis4u thanks for your response. I meant I want to use server side processing which many Laravel programmer does with install dependency package.. I wonder if I can make that processing without using that package. Please Google about Datatables Server Side, so you can get what I meant

Comment: What processing exactly? AJAX Datatables is a jQuery plugin and you are asking how to implement it without a package... You can do it by simply importing the css and js files that you need... it all depends what you need. if it's only to sort the table then you need only a few files.

Comment: I did it. So, it's possible then. how can I send JSON and view at the same time?  ---> `Response::json(['view' => \View::make('your.template', $yourData)->render()`]);`

Comment: @lewis4u Google it please.. it likes integration between PHP, Ajax, and that datatables itself. So whenever I try to edit my database, my datatables will keep sync with it. Even when I change it through phpmyadmin. most beautiful ajax feature

Comment: I can't google it...i work... but you can post a link here and I can see it later.

Comment: this one bro..https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/objects.html thanks for your help tho :) @lewis4u

Comment: hello bro @Chay22 I try your method.. there's no error but my view return white blank screen.
this is my eloquent query:
`$students = Student::whereIn('status', ['Inactive', 'Ungraduate'])->get(); `

Comment: That snippet I wrote above is just an example, it should be an object returned from controller's method which then translated automatically as a json response that you would likely need to handle on client side. That wasn't eloquent related, tho.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to make a response in your Controller like this:

```
$user = User::find(1);

return response()->json([
    'data' => [
        'name' => $user->name,
        'email' => $user->email 
    ]
]);
```

and then with ajax call it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "your_route_name",
        "columns": [
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "email" },
        ]
    } );
});
```

This is just an example on what you have explained. Of course it needs to be adapted to your needs.

Comment: There are tons features OP likely going to considerate. Pagination or sorting for instances, that probably any existing packages might have pass the struggles off. Help or fork, is better either. Don't mind me, just saying.

Comment: try your answer but still not get it.. because I cant run foreach in json. My `$user` variable is an array object.. and I think it must send JSON with return view. I'm new to this kind of JSON in Laravel tho, so sorry